# How can I use angluarJS to disable a button if a value is bigger than 255?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to use angularJS to disable a submit button if the textarea contains more than 255 letters. I dont use angularJS usually, so I dont really know how to do it. here is what i have:(HTML)

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="Messge" ng-model="message"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">Number of letters left: <span ng-bind="left()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="error" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

now here are the javascript files code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('userCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.messge = '';
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.incomplete = false;

    $scope.$watch('messge', function () { $scope.test(); });

    $scope.test = function () {
        if ($scope.messge.length > 255) {
            $scope.error = true;
        } else {
            $scope.error = false;
        }
    };
});
```

2nd file:

```
app.controller("myNoteCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.left = function () { return 255 - $scope.message.length; };
});
```

3rd file:

```
var app = angular.module("myNoteApp", []);
```

I found these codes in W3Schools, Altough i cant seem to make the button disabled. Can anyone help me with that? And if there is an easier way to combaine them all toghter in 1 file it would be great. if you still didnt understood what i meant, then tell me and ill try to explian it in a better way.
**TL;DR : I want to make a button become disabled when a textarea text length is bigger than 255.**

Comment: ng-disabled="messge.length > 255"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this all with angular expresions in html:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="Messge" ng-model="message"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">Number of letters left: {{255 - message.length}}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="message.length > 255" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Note how I also got rid of the `left()` function and replaced it with an angular expression. This means you can actually get rid of all your js files (or at least all that relate to this).